# Linearization of $\beta$-functions around Gaussian fixed points

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, effective-field-theory, phase-diagram

I was reading section 8.4.4 of the book "Condensed Matter Field Theory" by Altland & Simons and I ended up with a very specific question that I couldn't resolve.

After finding the Gaussian fixed points $(m_{\ast}^2, \lambda_{\ast}) = (0, 0)$ (trivial point) and $(m_{\ast}^2, \lambda_{\ast}) = \left(-\dfrac{\epsilon}{6}, \dfrac{16\epsilon\pi^2}{3}\right)$ (non-trivial point), the authors describe the linearization of the $\beta$ functions through two linear transformations:

\begin{equation*}
T_{1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & \frac{1}{16\pi^2} \\
0 & \epsilon
\end{bmatrix} \hspace{1cm} \& \hspace{1cm}
T_{2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2-\frac{\epsilon}{3} & \dfrac{1+\frac{\epsilon}{6}}{16\pi^2} \\
0 & -\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

However, I didn't understand where they got these two transformation matrices from. Furthermore, it's still not clear to me how this generates a phase diagram in the form:
[image]

> I'm using $r = m^2$, and the $\beta$ functions are:
>
> \begin{equation*} \beta(m^2) = 2m^2 + \dfrac{\lambda}{16\pi^2} -
>  \dfrac{\lambda m^2}{16\pi^2} \hspace{1cm} \& \hspace{1cm}
>  \beta(\lambda) = \epsilon\lambda - \dfrac{3\lambda^2}{16\pi^2}
>  \end{equation*}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Please make the question self-contained so that someone else can benefit.

Given that you already know the $\beta$ functions for the theory, given by the equation **(8.30)** (discarding the last one) in the book:
$$ \frac{dr}{d\ell} = 2r + \frac{\lambda}{16\pi^{2}} - \frac{r\lambda}{16\pi^{2}}, \qquad\qquad \frac{d\lambda}{d\ell} = \epsilon\lambda - \frac{3\lambda}{16\pi^{2}} $$

The fixed points associated with these equations are given, namely $(r^{*}_{1},\lambda^{*}_{1}) = (0,0)$ and $(r^{*}_{2},\lambda^{*}_{2}) = (-\frac{1}{6}\epsilon,\frac{16\pi^{2}}{3}\epsilon)$.

It is natural to pay special attention to the behavior of the flow in the immediate vicinity of the *fixed-point manifolds*. The recipe for that is the following:

Write down the Gell-Mann–Low equation (equation 8.17 in **AS**)
$$ \frac{d\mathbf{g}}{d\ell} = R(\mathbf{g})  $$

If the set of coupling constants, $g$, is only close enough to a fixed point, $g^{*}$, it will be sufficient to consider the linearized mapping

$$ R(\mathbf{g}) = R((\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{g}^{*})+\mathbf{g}^{*}) \approx W(\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{g}^{*}) $$

Where $W(\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{g}^{*})$ is a matrix in the RG space, which has the form
$$ W_{ab} =  \frac{\partial R_{a}}{\partial g_{b}}\vert_{g=g^{*}} $$

By studying the eigensystem of the $W$ matrix, one can classify different terms appearing in the action as **relevant**, **irrelevant**, and **marginal** (**AS** page 435).

Now your $R_{1} = 2r + \frac{\lambda}{16\pi^{2}} - \frac{r\lambda}{16\pi^{2}}$ and $R_{2} = \epsilon\lambda - \frac{3\lambda}{16\pi^{2}}$. Take derivatives with respect of $r$ and $\lambda$ and evaluate each of them for $(r^{*}_{1},\lambda^{*}_{1})$ and $(r^{*}_{2},\lambda^{*}_{2})$ and inserting them into the definition of $W$ matrix will leads to the matrix $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$. Which is your $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$.